# Remove specific CSV columns from large CSV file and duplicated rows with Perl

Tags: perl

I have a large CSV file (300MB+) and I want to remove only columns 2,3 and 6-8 using Perl AND remove duplicated rows:

Note 1: all columns are separated by `,` (commas) but sometimes my cell values contains a `,` or multiple `,` and are separated by `"` (see last row, columns 9 and 10); thus I'd like still be able to process the input.csv file even if it has `,` inside the cells:

Note 2: I've added links to the input.csv and output.csv files:

[input.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fxs30dojyovpf1j/input.csv?dl=0)

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 2,info 3,...,info 10
address 1,address 2,....,address 10
city 1,city 2,city 3,city 4,city 5,city 6,city 7,city 8,"city 9, extra","city 10, new"
```

[output.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju9wbrkttykf000/output.csv?dl=0)

```
Col1,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 4,info 5,info 9,info 10
address 1,address 4,address 5,address 9,address 10
city 1,city 4,city 5,"city 9, extra","city 10, new"
```

I've found a Perl command that would remove the last column using regex, but don't know if it's good enough or how to tweak it to suit my case (any other suggestion is more than welcomed!):

```
perl -pe 's/.*\K,.*//'
```

Is it possible to remove only columns 2,3 and 6-8 using Perl and remove any duplicated rows?

PS: updated the input.csv file to include duplicate rows as well

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure you show us an example that accurately recreates your file. We need to be able to test our solutions and we can't do that with the file you have given us. Also, if this is a complex CSV with `,` inside fields protected by quotes, we need to know this.

Comment: @terdon I will update my question, thank you!

Comment: question was updated with more accurate info and links to input.csv and output.csv files

Comment: Removing duplicates is simple if the input is already sorted (pipe through `uniq`), or if you don't mind it being sorted (use `sort -u`). Otherwise your perl script will need to remember each line that it has seen (e.g. in a hash variable, `%seen` is a good name for this purpose), which can take significant amounts of RAM (300MB input file is unlikely to be a problem on any modern system). If there is a unique identifier in each row, you can use that, otherwise you'll probably have to use the entire row - e.g. `next if $seen{$_}++;` or perhaps an md5sum of the row to reduce RAM at cost of CPU

Comment: thanks a lot @cas , yes, there's no unique identifier for my rows, so i will have to use the entire row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) aka `mlr`, which is a great tool for working with data in CSV, json, and a few other input or output formats.  For example:

```
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output \
    cut -x -f 2,3,6,7,8 \
    then uniq -a input.csv  
Col1,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 4,5,9,info 10
address 1,4,5,9,address 10
city 1,4,5,9,city 10
```

Using both the `--implicit-csv-header` and `--headerless-csv-output` options effectively ignores the header line (i.e. treat it the same as the other data lines) and allow me to specify the fields to be cut by number rather than by name.

I had to edit your sample input.csv file to add some junk data in the missing fields.  `mlr` would have complained otherwise.  I also added a duplicate input line to test that the dupe elimination was working.

```
$ cat input.csv 
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 2,info 3,info 4,5,6,7,8,9,info 10
info 1,info 2,info 3,info 4,5,6,7,8,9,info 10
address 1,address 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,address 10
city 1, city 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,city 10
```

---

If you want to do it with perl:

1. If you only need to handle simple comma-delimited input:

```
$ perl -F, -lane '
  next if $seen{$_}++;
  splice @F,5,3;
  splice @F,1,2;
  print join ",", @F' input.csv
Col1,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 4,5,9,info 10
address 1,4,5,9,address 10
city 1,4,5,9,city 10
```

This uses perl's `-a` option to auto-split each input line into an array called `@F`.  The `-F` option tells it what delimiter to use.

Note 1: perl arrays start from zero, not one...so array element 5 is column 6.  `splice @$row, 5, 3` removes three elements from the array starting from element 5 (i.e. columns 6,7,8).  See `perldoc -f splice` for details.

Note 2: I am deleting the columns in reverse order here (i.e. higher-numbered columns **before** lower-numbered).  Otherwise, if I deleted columns 2 & 3 before deleting columns 5,6,7, the first deletion would cause those columns to be renumbered (to 3,4,5)

2. Using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) to handle any valid CSV (including things like multi-line quoted columns containing commas):

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -e '
  my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
  while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
    next if $seen{join ",", @$row}++;
    splice @$row, 5, 3;
    splice @$row, 1, 2;
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
  }' input.csv
Col1,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10
"info 1","info 4",5,9,"info 10"
"address 1",4,5,9,"address 10"
"city 1",4,5,9,"city 10"
```

There are four things worth noting here:

1. `Text::CSV` is not a core perl module, so it needs to be installed.  It's packaged for most, if not all, Linux distributions.  e.g. on Debian, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl`.  Otherwise, you can install it with the `cpan` command which comes with perl.
2. Text::CSV's `getline()` method (as in `$row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)` above) returns a reference to an array, or arrayref.  That's a scalar value that points to an entire array (see `man perlref` and `man perldata` for more info).
3. `$row` in the code above contains the arrayref.  Using/manipulating $row works on the reference itself, not the data it is referencing.  So, e.g., `$row2 = $row` makes a copy of the reference, not the data.  Both refs point to the same data. `@$row` "de-references" the arrayref as an array, so that it can be used just like any other array.
4. The `*ARGV` in `getline(*ARGV)` is a special file handle that reads input from ALL filename arguments given on the command line (which are stored in an array called @ARGV in perl).  It is assumed that non-filename arguments (e.g. options, if your script has code to handle options) have already been processed and removed from @ARGV.  Filenames that don't exist or can't be opened (e.g. due to permissions) will produce an error message.  In short, it reads from one or more filenames that you give it.  An argument of `-` is treated as stdin, so it can read input from file(s), stdin, or both.

This is a really simple & primitive example of what Text::CSV is capable of and how it can be used.  Read the man page for more details and examples.

As you can see in the sample output above, Text::CSV will, by default, quote text fields if they contain a space.  If you don't want it to do that, you can override that by setting the `quote_space` attribute to zero....either when you create the $csv object with the `new` method:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ quote_space => 0 });
```

or afterwards:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
$csv->quote_space(0);
```

The output would then be like this:

```
Col1,Col4,Col5,Col9,Col10
info 1,info 4,5,9,info 10
address 1,4,5,9,address 10
city 1,4,5,9,city 10
```

Comment: thanks a lot @cas!!! both methods 1 & 2 worked great and deduplicated the rows and removed the columns even when having commas in some cells. Can you please confirm I got this right? so this command ```splice @$row, 5, 3;``` will remove Col 6 (which is actually Col 5 in Perl) and the next 3 columns, so it'd remove Col 6,7,8; next remove Col 2,3 so this command ```splice @$row, 1, 2;``` removes Col 1 (which is actually Col 2 in Perl) and the next 2 columns. I've made a screenshot here with this here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bqngom7jx1w0jh/remove%20columns.png?dl=0), is it correct?

Comment: Not exactly.  it deletes three columns, not four.  `splice @$row, 5, 3` will remove three columns starting from the sixth column (with column numbering starting from zero) , not col 6 and the next 3 cols, so columns 6-8 not 6-9.  This form of the `splice` function is summarised as `splice ARRAY,OFFSET,LENGTH`.  There are other forms that allow splice to be used to insert or replace columns.   See `perldoc -f splice` for more details.   Really, the only slightly tricky thing you need to remember is that perl arrays start from zero, and that's common to lots of languages, including C and bash.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation @cas , greatly appreciated! got it!

Answer (score 2):

Turn it into an array, think about, recreate it as a csv:

```
perl -pe '@c = split(","); splice(@c, 1, 2); splice(@c, 3, 3); $_ = join(", ", @c)
```

If you're fields are quoted, you can use `Text::CSV`:

```
$ cat in.csv 
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
one,two,three,four,five
six,"se,ven","ei,ght",nine,ten
$ perl -MText::CSV -e 'Text::CSV::csv( in => "in.csv", headers => false, on_in => sub { splice( @{@_[1]}, 1, 2) } )'
Col1,Col4,Col5
one,four,five
six,nine,ten
```

You ask about perl, but for the sake awareness also consider the cut tool:
`cut -f '1,4,5,9,10' -d ,`

Comment: so I tried cut but if the CSV has commas in it ```,``` then it ends up not processing the whole file and stopping

Comment: I've also seen other users use this module https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV  to read and write CSV files in Perl which is apparently great for CSV files, but I don't know how to use it; ideally i'd do it through a perl script that uses that module

Comment: OK, yes.  if your fields have embedded ','s (presumably wrapped in "s), life get's a bit harder.
The doc for that module looks pretty good, with some examples that should get you going pretty quick.

Comment: See edit for an example using `Text::CSV`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ garethhumphriesgkc. I tried this Perl terminal command to remove those specific columns and output to a new output.csv file `$ perl -MText::CSV -e 'Text::CSV::csv( in => "input.csv", headers => false, on_in => sub { splice( @{@_[1]}, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8) } )' >> output.csv` but it's just adding numbers in the columns like 3,6,7,8 and not removing them

Comment: Do you know how the splice command works?  You'll need a few splices, like in my top example.

Comment: I'll keep trying it until I get it working. I realised that above command was missing a `'` at the end and i was getting errors, so using this command now testing it `perl -pe '@c = split(","); splice(@c, 1, 2); splice(@c, 3, 3); $_ = join(", ", @c)' input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: You'll need a `<` before the `input.csv`.  `perl -pe` take input on standard in - it won't open any files automatically.  Either `cat input.csv | perl -pe '...'` or `perl -pe '...' < input.csv` will do that for you.

Comment: @garethhumphriesgkc   `perl -p` works on stdin and/or any filename arg(s) you give it.    As does `perl -n`.   They're effectively an implicit `while (<>) {...}` loop around the `-e` script.  See `man perlrun` and search for the `-n` and `-p` definitions.  See also `man perlop` and search for **I/O Operators**, in particular read about the null filehandle or `<>` and `<<>>` operators (sometimes known as "diamond" or "double diamond" operators respectively, so just search for diamond in the perlop man page).

Comment: @garethhumphriesgkc thanks for the awesome info, I've used the command you suggested and it worked great ```perl -pe '@c = split(","); splice(@c, 1, 2); splice(@c, 3, 3); $_ = join(", ", @c)' < input.csv > output.csv``` . The command does not de-duplicate the duplicated rows, but that wasn't initially in the question's info